# JQuery - remove text after character, keep string comma seperated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string:

```
XXX - Test Text 1, OOO - Test Text 2, Dummy
```

What I want to do is return this string as:

```
XXX,OOO,Dummy
```

So I need to remove everything (and including the dash) but keep the string comma separated. This string could have up to say 10 variables.

Comment: Please share what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery, it is just native JavaScript. What you could do is split the string for every comma. Then split every part on the `-` character and join all the parts together:

```js
parsedString = "XXX - Test Text 1, OOO - Test Text 2, Dummy".split(',')
  .map(part => part.split('-')[0].trim())
  .join(',')

console.log(parsedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can first [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string which will returns an array of strings

```
str.split(",")
```

**2)** use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to only get the initial string of all strings in an array that is returned from the 1st step

**3)** then, [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them with `,`

```js
const str = "XXX - Test Text 1, OOO - Test Text 2, Dummy";
const result = str
  .split(",")
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let match = curr.match(/[a-z]+/i);
    if (match) acc.push(match[0]);
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .join(",");

console.log(result);
```